# Adjust non-uniform spacing only observed with a font

Tags: spacing, xetex

I'm using Adishila fonts (https://adishila.com/fonts/) to prepare a document and notice that the spacing between some words is not uniform. I'm using `~` to ensure that certain words do not appear at the beginning of a line.

I don't see the spacing issue when using a different font (Sanskrit 2003) and hence wonder if this is an issue with the font. Is there a way to fix the irregular spacing that appears with the Adishila font? I've commented out some portion in my MWE that requires installation of additional fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\setlength\parindent{0ex}
\usepackage[british,babel,sanskrit, provide=*]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
pratipadārthaḥ \contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}
\textit{\textbf{tataḥ anu}}~= sarasvatyāḥ vacanānantaram~;
\textit{\textbf{tat\textup{+}visphurat\textup{+}phaṇa\textup{+}vilokana\textup{+}bhūta\textup{+}bhīteḥ}}  $\rightarrow$   tat~= vāsukeḥ, visphurat~=  viśālībhūya calatām, phaṇa~=  phaṇānām, vilokana~=  darśanena, bhūta~=  jātāt, bhīteḥ~=  bhayāt~;
\textit{\textbf{tasyāḥ}}~=  damayantyāḥ~;
\textit{\textbf{kampam}}~= kampam~;
\textit{\textbf{pulakaṃ ca}}~= romāñcaṃ ca~;
\textit{\textbf{vīkṣya}}~=  dṛṣṭvā~;
\textit{\textbf{saṃjāta\textup{+}sāttvika\textup{+}vikāra\textup{+}dhiyaḥ}}  $\rightarrow$   saṃjāta~= udbhūtānām, sāttvikavikāra~=  śṛṅgārarasasambandhināṃ sāttvikabhāvānāṃ yaḥ, dhiyaḥ~= bhramaḥ tadvataḥ (sāttvikabhāvāḥ iti bhramaṃ prāptavataḥ)~;
\textit{\textbf{sva\textup{+}bhṛtyān}}~=  svīyasevakān~;
\textit{\textbf{vilakṣaḥ}}~=  damayantyāḥ hṛdayaṃ jñātvā lajjitaḥ~;
\textit{\textbf{uraga\textup{+}adhipatiḥ}}~=  sarparājaḥ vāsukiḥ~;
\textit{\textbf{nṛtyāt}}~=  ānandanāṭyāt~;
\textit{\textbf{nyaṣedhat}}~=  nivāritavān~.
\end{sloppypar}
\vspace{5mm}

% This section requires installing sanskrit 2003 and Adishila fonts
% Sanskrit2003 can be downloaded from https://omkarananda-ashram.org/Sanskrit/sanskrit2003.zip
% Adishila can be downloaded from  https://adishila.com/fonts/
%\newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
%\newfontfamily\myfontas[Script=Devanagari,Scale=1.6]{Adishila San}
%\textbf{\underline{With Sankskrit2003}}:
%\vspace{5mm}
%\begin{sloppypar}
%{\myfont
%प्रतिपदार्थः \contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}
%\textit{ततः अनु}~= सरस्वत्याः वचनानन्तरम्~;
%\textit{तत्\textup{+}विस्फुरत्\textup{+}फण\textup{+}विलोकन\textup{+}भूत\textup{+}भीतेः}  $\rightarrow$   तत्~= वासुकेः, विस्फुरत्~=  विशालीभूय चलताम्, फण~=  फणानाम्, विलोकन~=  दर्शनेन, भूत~=  जातात्, भीतेः~=  भयात्~;
%\textit{तस्याः}~=  दमयन्त्याः~;
%\textit{कम्पम्}~= कम्पम्~;
%\textit{पुलकं च}~= रोमाञ्चं च~;
%\textit{वीक्ष्य}~=  दृष्ट्वा~;
%\textit{संजात\textup{+}सात्त्विक\textup{+}विकार\textup{+}धियः}  $\rightarrow$   संजात~= उद्भूतानाम्, सात्त्विकविकार~=  शृङ्गाररससम्बन्धिनां सात्त्विकभावानां यः, धियः~= भ्रमः तद्वतः (सात्त्विकभावाः इति भ्रमं प्राप्तवतः)~;
%\textit{स्व\textup{+}भृत्यान्}~=  स्वीयसेवकान्~;
%\textit{विलक्षः}~=  दमयन्त्याः हृदयं ज्ञात्वा लज्जितः~;
%\textit{उरग\textup{+}अधिपतिः}~=  सर्पराजः वासुकिः~;
%\textit{नृत्यात्}~=  आनन्दनाट्यात्~;
%\textit{न्यषेधत्}~=  निवारितवान्~।
%}
%\end{sloppypar}
%
%
%\vspace{5mm}
%\underline{\textbf{With Adishila}}:
%\vspace{5mm}
%\begin{sloppypar}
%{\myfontas
%प्रतिपदार्थः \contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}
%\textit{\textbf{ततः अनु}}~= सरस्वत्याः वचनानन्तरम्~;
%\textit{\textbf{तत्\textup{+}विस्फुरत्\textup{+}फण\textup{+}विलोकन\textup{+}भूत\textup{+}भीतेः}}  $\rightarrow$   तत्~= वासुकेः, विस्फुरत्~=  विशालीभूय चलताम्, फण~=  फणानाम्, विलोकन~=  दर्शनेन, भूत~=  जातात्, भीतेः~=  भयात्~;
%\textit{\textbf{तस्याः}}~=  दमयन्त्याः~;
%\textit{\textbf{कम्पम्}}~= कम्पम्~;
%\textit{\textbf{पुलकं च}}~= रोमाञ्चं च~;
%\textit{\textbf{वीक्ष्य}}~=  दृष्ट्वा~;
%\textit{\textbf{संजात\textup{+}सात्त्विक\textup{+}विकार\textup{+}धियः}}  $\rightarrow$   संजात~= उद्भूतानाम्, सात्त्विकविकार~=  शृङ्गाररससम्बन्धिनां सात्त्विकभावानां यः, धियः~= भ्रमः तद्वतः (सात्त्विकभावाः इति भ्रमं प्राप्तवतः)~;
%\textit{\textbf{स्व\textup{+}भृत्यान्}}~=  स्वीयसेवकान्~;
%\textit{\textbf{विलक्षः}}~=  दमयन्त्याः हृदयं ज्ञात्वा लज्जितः~;
%\textit{\textbf{उरग\textup{+}अधिपतिः}}~=  सर्पराजः वासुकिः~;
%\textit{\textbf{नृत्यात्}}~=  आनन्दनाट्यात्~;
%\textit{\textbf{न्यषेधत्}}~=  निवारितवान्~।
%}
%\end{sloppypar}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: if you use a justified paragraph (and don't use microtype) then adjusting the inter word space is the only way to achieve justification so it is expected that some lines have tighter word spacing than others.

Comment: TeX treats “tat+visphurat+phaṇa+vilokana+bhūta+bhīteḥ“ as a single unbreakable work. Insert `\allowbreak`s after (or before) the + signs.